Insert arrows and coloring them in React
I had to work onn the component bellow to show a pdf then saving it in the machine :

So I made the following react code where :
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import "jspdf-autotable";

function App() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState("");
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState("");
  const [matrix, setMatrix] = useState([]);

  // Define midCol here
  const midCol = Math.floor(columns / 2) - 2;

  function generateSchema(rows, columns) {
    const table = [];
    const midCol = Math.floor(columns / 2) - 2;
    const increment = 17;
    const increment2 = 25;
    const increment3 = 42;

    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      table.push(new Array(columns).fill(0));
    }

    for (let i = midCol - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      table[0][i] = table[0][i + 1] + increment;
    }
    table[0][midCol + 1] = table[0][midCol] + increment2;
    for (let i = midCol + 2; i < columns; i++) {
      table[0][i] = table[0][i - 1] + increment;
    }

    for (let row = 1; row < rows; row++) {
      if (row % 2 === 0) {
        table[row][midCol] = table[row - 1][midCol] + increment3;
        table[row][midCol + 1] = table[row][midCol] + increment2;
        for (let i = midCol + 2; i < columns; i++) {
          table[row][i] = table[row][i - 1] + increment;
        }
        for (let i = midCol - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          table[row][i] = table[row][i + 1] + increment;
        }
      } else {
        table[row][midCol + 1] = table[row - 1][midCol + 1] + increment3;
        table[row][midCol] = table[row][midCol + 1] + increment2;
        for (let i = midCol + 2; i < columns; i++) {
          table[row][i] = table[row][i - 1] + increment;
        }
        for (let i = midCol - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          table[row][i] = table[row][i + 1] + increment;
        }
      }
    }

    return table;
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const rowsValue = parseInt(rows);
    const columnsValue = parseInt(columns);
    const schema = generateSchema(rowsValue, columnsValue);
    setMatrix(schema);

    // Generate PDF
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    const tableData = schema.map((row) => row.map((cell) => String(cell)));

    // Add logos
    const logoLeft = new Image();
    logoLeft.src = "./";
    doc.addImage(logoLeft, "JPEG", 10, 10, 50, 50);

    const logoRight = new Image();
    logoRight.src = "./ocpDePdf.jpg";
    doc.addImage(logoRight, "JPEG", 150, 10, 50, 50);

    // Add titles
    doc.setFontSize(20);
    doc.text("Schéma de TIR", 105, 40, null, null, "center");

    doc.setFontSize(14);
    doc.text("19/02/2024", 105, 50, null, null, "center");

    // Add matrix
    doc.autoTable({
      head: [
        ["", ...Array.from({ length: columnsValue }, (_, i) => `${i + 1}`)],
      ], // Column headers
      body: tableData.map((row, index) => {
        const rowData = [`L${index + 1}`, ...row];
        if (index === 0) {
          // Add arrows for the first row
          rowData[midCol + 1] = "→";
          rowData.forEach((cell, cellIndex) => {
            if (cellIndex <= midCol && cellIndex !== midCol + 1) {
              rowData[cellIndex] = "←";
            } else if (cellIndex > midCol + 1) {
              rowData[cellIndex] = "→";
            }
          });
        } else if (index % 2 === 0) {
          // Add arrows for even rows
          rowData[midCol + 1] = "↓";
          rowData[midCol] = "←";
          rowData.forEach((cell, cellIndex) => {
            if (cellIndex > midCol + 1) {
              rowData[cellIndex] = "→";
            }
          });
        } else {
          // Add arrows for odd rows
          rowData[midCol + 1] = "↓";
          rowData[midCol + 2] = "←";
          rowData.forEach((cell, cellIndex) => {
            if (cellIndex <= midCol) {
              rowData[cellIndex] = "→";
            }
          });
        }
        return rowData;
      }), // Line numbers
      startY: 60,
    });

    //doc.save("matrix.pdf");
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="rows">Nombre de lignes:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="rows"
          name="rows"
          value={rows}
          onChange={(e) => setRows(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <label htmlFor="columns">Nombre de colonnes:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="columns"
          name="columns"
          value={columns}
          onChange={(e) => setColumns(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">Générer</button>
      </form>

      <table id="matrix">
        <tbody>
          
          {matrix.map((row, rowIndex) => (
            <tr key={rowIndex}>
              <th>{`L${rowIndex + 1}`}</th>
              {row.map((cell, cellIndex) => {
                let arrowClass = "";
                let arrowSymbol = "";
                if (rowIndex === 0) {
                  arrowSymbol = cellIndex <= midCol ? "←" : "→";
                  arrowClass =
                    cellIndex === midCol + 1
                      ? "yellow"
                      : cellIndex <= midCol
                      ? "green-left"
                      : "green-right";
                } else if (rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
                  arrowSymbol =
                    cellIndex === midCol + 1
                      ? "↓→"
                      : cellIndex <= midCol
                      ? "←"
                      : "→";
                  arrowClass =
                    cellIndex === midCol + 1
                      ? "yellow red-down-left"
                      : cellIndex <= midCol
                      ? "green-left"
                      : "green-right";
                } else {
                  arrowSymbol =
                    cellIndex === midCol + 1
                      ? "←↓"
                      : cellIndex <= midCol
                      ? "←"
                      : "→";
                  arrowClass =
                    cellIndex === midCol + 1
                      ? "yellow red-down-right"
                      : cellIndex <= midCol
                      ? "green-left"
                      : "green-right";
                }
                return (
                  <td key={cellIndex} className={arrowClass}>
                    {cell}
                    {arrowSymbol}
                  </td>
                );
              })}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

However when saving the pdf, the arrows doesn't show, instead I have random caractères and the coloring it applied too. The logo doesn't appear on the pdf page & the result is far from what it has to be.
I need to have the exact result, so hoping you can help me with it.. THANKS IN ADVANCE !
